# More than one title we have but how can i get it in array laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

we have to find quiz title associated with question id, but there are more than one quiz with same question id. we get in return one one quiz title not all. what can i do?

```
$questions = DB::table('questionbank')
               
        ->leftJoin('questionbank_quizzes', function($join)
     {
         $join->on('questionbank_quizzes.questionbank_id','=','questionbank.id');
              
     })
     ->leftJoin('quizzes', function($join)
     {
         $join->on('quizzes.id','=','questionbank_quizzes.quize_id');
              
     })
       
        ->where('questionbank.subject_id', '=', $request->subject_id)
        ->get(['questionbank.id', 'questionbank.subject_id', 'topic_id', 'question_type', 'question', 'questionbank.marks', 'difficulty_level', 'status','quizzes.title']);
```

I tried to use whereIn but we got error

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Welcome to SO ... there are many `questionbank` with a particular `subject_id`?

Answer (score 0):

At the first, you should make a `relationship` between your models:

QuestionBank model:

```php
 public function quizzes()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Quiz::class);
 }
```

Quiz model:

```php
 public function questions()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany(QuestionBank::class);
 }
```

now you can use the `eloquent` class for your queries:

```php
$questions = QuestionBank::with('quizzes')
    ->where('subject_id', $request->subject_id)
    ->get()

foreach ($questions as $question) {
    // you have access to $question->quizzes as collection
}
```